# Change post count on tag/terms pages to 10

Tags: php, wordpress, function, tags, taxonomy-terms

I have modified my search results page with a function to change the search results count to 10. How can I do the same thing, but for the tag/terms pages?

```
function change_wp_search_size($query) {
    if ($query->is_search) // Make sure it is a search page
        $query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = 10; // Change 10 to the number of posts you would like to show
    return $query; // Return our modified query variables
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'change_wp_search_size'); // Hook our custom function onto the request filter
```

Found and tried this code and it didnt work

```
function main_query_mods($query) {
    // check http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags to play with other queries
    if (!$query->is_main_query()) {
        return;
    }
    if (is_tag()) {
        $query->set('posts_per_page', 10);
    }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'main_query_mods');
```

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is with your `is_tag()`; you have to it like this
>   `$query->is_tag()`.

```
function main_query_mods($query) {
    if ($query->is_tag() && $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin()) {
        $query->set('posts_per_page', 10);
    }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'main_query_mods');
```

---

**UPDATED**

> If you want to limit post by 10 on both `tag` and `search` page then
>   you have to use `is_tag()` and `is_search()` together in your `if`
>   statement.

```
function wh_tag_search_postCount($query) {
    if (($query->is_tag() || $query->is_search()) && $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin()) {
        $query->set('posts_per_page', 10);
    }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'wh_tag_search_postCount');
```

---

**UPDATED** *v3*

> If you want to exclude shop page then you can use `is_shop()` and
>   `is_product_category()` for product category archive page.

```
function wh_tag_search_postCount($query) {
    //if WooCommerce is active
    if (class_exists('WooCommerce')) {
        //if current page is a shop page or product category page then dont do any thing
        if (is_shop() || is_product_category())
            return;
    }
    if (($query->is_tag() || $query->is_search()) && $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin()) {
        $query->set('posts_per_page', 10);
    }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'wh_tag_search_postCount');
```

*All the code is tested and works.*
Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried this and with my search code, when I add this new function, neither post counts are 10.

Comment: @EmilyG: I have updated my answer. `wh_tag_search_postCount()` will work for both of your post count.

Comment: Search is showing 10 posts correctly but the tag page is still displaying only 5 posts. [link](https://www.baby-chick.com/tag/pregnancy/)

Comment: If you had used `wh_tag_search_postCount()` then should show 10 post count on both search and tag page. I think then it getting overwrite by another theme function. for debugging you can deactivate all plugin and change your theme. because I have tested the code and it is fully working. So I think the issue some where else.

Comment: Yep - I agree. Thank you for your help Raunak!

Comment: Hi again!! So I realized after getting the code working that it is also limiting the number of products on the shop page to 10 as well :( How can I exclude the products from this function? I have tried adding `!is_post_type_archive( 'products' )` with no effect.